# Regex similar data differently and populate dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have blocks of information that contain two 10 character alphanumeric codes in the format `xxxxx-xxxxx`. The below text is an example of how data could be presented. There will always be one 'parent' number and any number of 'child' numbers.

Pandas ver: 23.4

```
12345-78901
    a:a
    b:b {
    54321-98765
    a:a
    b:b
}


12345-99999
    a:a
    b:b {
    54321-47382
    a:a
    b:b
    7test-38472
    a:a
    b:b
}
```

The idea is to regex the first number `12345-78901` in one capture group, and the second number `54321-98765` in a separate group so that neither show up in the same regex search. My thinking is to read the two different capture groups into dataframe columns. The result df after reading in the following text would be as follows:

```
Parent       Child
12345-78901  54321-98765
12345-99999  54321-47382
12345-99999  7test-38472
```

Where I am stuck is how to differentiate what is a parent and what is a child, my approach was to look at indentation. Code below:

```
df = pd.read_csv(txt, header=None, sep='\\', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
numA = df[0].str.extractall(r'(.....-.....)')
numB = df[0].str.extractall(r'(    .....-.....)')
df_out = pd.concat([numA, numB], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

However this populates all numbers into `numA` and leaves `numB` blank, any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `r'(.....-.....)'` also matches the indented numbers. You could avoid this by specifying where exactly the beginning of the line is. So something like:

`r'(^.....-.....)'` and `r'(^    .....-.....)'`

The circumflex `^` stands for the beginning of the line. If you know the characters are numbers better use `\d`. So something like `r'(\d{5}-\d{5})'`. For the circumflex the multiline flag of `pandas.Series.str.extractall` has to be set.

Comment: I am a bit confused as I don't see the difference between `r'(^.....-.....)'` and `r'(^.....-.....)'`.

Comment: The second one is with spaces. If you mark it, you'll see the spaces...

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using `str.findall`

**Ex:**

```
s = """12345-78901
    a:a
    b:b {
    54321-98765
    a:a
    b:b
}
"""
s2 = """12345-99999
    a:a
    b:b {
    54321-47382
    a:a
    b:b
    7test-38472
    a:a
    b:b
}"""
df = pd.DataFrame({"temp":[s, s2]})
data = df["temp"].str.findall(r"(\w+\-\w+)").apply(lambda x: [{'Parent': x[0], "Child": i} for i in x[1:]]).tolist()
print(pd.DataFrame.from_records(np.concatenate(data)))
```

**Output:**

```
         Child       Parent
0  54321-98765  12345-78901
1  54321-47382  12345-99999
2  7test-38472  12345-99999
```

Comment: for some reason `data` populates, but when trying to concatenate it to new df or print it nothing shows.